# Cannot run program. The system cannot find the specified file

Tags: java

I am getting the following error while trying to run a program:

```
Cannot run program. Error:Cannot run program 
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin\java" (in directory 
"C:\Users\Lenovo\.IdeaIC2017.3\system\compile-server"): CreateProcess error=2, 
The system cannot find the file specified
```

Here is the Java code I'm trying to compile and run:

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Teacher t = new Teacher("Jan","Kowalski",30098513256L);
        t.setDegree("mgr inż.");
        t.info();

        Student s = new Student("Janek", "Kowalewski", 20456815698L, 1542);
        s.info();
    }
}
```

Comment: What command are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

Disable antivirus if you have one.

Copy the jar.exe from java bin folder and paste to the JRE bin folder.

Set the Environment variable correctly.

See if disabling UAC helps (Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > User Accounts > Change User Account Control settings and move the slider down).

Relocate IDE folder. Here is an article on how to do that:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207240985

Hope some of this will help.

Answer (score 0):

JDK 1.8.0_152 has known problems running in IDEA (It seems like that's what you are using.) Try updating to a newer version of Java 8.